# PSTricks displaying incorrect axis arrow at origin

Tags: pstricks

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\begin{document}
    \psset{xunit=0.45}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-.5)(10.5,2)
        \psaxes[]{<->}(0,0)(-3,0)(11,1.5)[$n$,0][$x[n]$,90]
        \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{9}{t | 0.5^t}{A}
        \psset{linecolor=red}
        \multido{\i=0+1}{\numexpr\Anodecount+1}{\psline{-o}(!\i\space dt mul 0)(A\i)}
        \psline{-o}(-1,0)(-1,0)
        \psline{-o}(-2,0)(-2,0)
        \psline{-o}(10,0)(10,0)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: Resulting Plot]

Based on the PSTricks documentation, the arrow at the origin should not be there.  Am I missing something or is this a bug?  When I try the example given from the PSTricks documentation (see the psaxes section), it produces an erroneous arrow as well.  Any thoughts on a temporary fix to get rid of the arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set two axes, one with the y-axis definitions, and another with the x-axis definitions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.45}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-.5)(10.5,2)
  \psaxes[yAxis=false]{<->}(0,0)(-3,0)(11,1.5)[$n$,0][,90]
  \psaxes[xAxis=false]{->}(0,0)(-3,0)(11,1.5)[,0][$x[n]$,90]
  %\psaxes[]{->}(0,0)(-3,0)(11,1.5)[$n$,0][$x[n]$,90]
  \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{9}{t | 0.5^t}{A}
  \psset{linecolor=red}
  \multido{\i=0+1}{\numexpr\Anodecount+1}{\psline{-o}(!\i\space dt mul 0)(A\i)}
  \psline{-o}(-1,0)(-1,0)
  \psline{-o}(-2,0)(-2,0)
  \psline{-o}(10,0)(10,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: More concise and much less "hackish" than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

By default `\psaxes` creates both axes with the same arrow style. In this case, you want x with double arrows, and y with a single arrow. To get that you have to define the two axes separately.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\begin{document}
    \psset{xunit=0.45}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-.5)(12,2)
        \psaxes[xAxis=false,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(0,1.5)
        \psyTick{0}(1){1}
        \psaxes[yAxis=false]{<->}(0,0)(-3,0)(11,0)
        \uput[0](11,0){$n$}
        \uput[90](0,1.5){$x[n]$}
        \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{9}{t | 0.5^t}{A}
        \psset{linecolor=red}
        \multido{\i=0+1}{\numexpr\Anodecount+1}{\psline{-o}(!\i\space dt mul 0)(A\i)}
        \psline{-o}(-1,0)(-1,0)
        \psline{-o}(-2,0)(-2,0)
        \psline{-o}(10,0)(10,0)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]